# saving/retrieving R objects in a database, or other solutions for object persistence in R

Tags: r, database, object, client-server, persistence

I am developing a server side R application, and I need some object persistence capability. That is, a way to store object X for user Y, so that if the server crashes, or if user Y logs back in in a while, then the last version of her/his version of object X can be easily restored. Ideally this would also be accompanied with an "admin" capability, so that an admin can see which users and which objects where stored and when (mainly for debugging and backup purposes).

working with a database is fine, but the objects are typically not tabular but general objects (like glm models, graphs, etc.), so SQL connection to a relational db is not an ideal solution.

I wonder if there is a package that provides such capability, or if you have any suggestions about how to do it. my first "intuition" is to try to implement such capability with a simple file system and the save/load functions. but this seems overly simplistic and error prone.

any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can you just use a git solution such as github and store the files there? This gives you persistence + version control. `saveRDS` let you save all R objects into files.

Comment: This maybe a feasible solution, my worry is that once there are too many users there wil be too many files there and harder to manage.